# replace strings with placeholders in python

Tags: python

I am trying to replace the variables with placeholders like XXX. The words "hello" and "morning" are printed as-is because they appear in another list.  The following code works, but prints extra placeholders.

```
import re

mylist = ['hello', 'morning']
nm = [
    "Hello World Robot Morning.",
    "Hello Aniket Fine Morning.",
    "Hello Paresh Good and bad Morning.",
]



def punctuations(string):
    pattern = re.compile(r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b")
    result = pattern.match(string)
    myword = result.group()
    return myword


for x in nm:
    newlist = list()
    for y in x.split():
        for z in mylist:
            if z.lower() == punctuations(y.lower()):
                newlist.append(y)
            else:
                newlist.append("xxx")
    print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'Morning.']
['Hello', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'Morning.']
['Hello', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'Morning.']
```

Expected output:

```
['Hello', 'xxx', 'xxx',  'Morning.']
['Hello', 'xxx', 'xxx',   'Morning.']
['Hello', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'Morning.']
```

Comment: Can you explain your code, is it a arbitrary exercise, or any specific purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to break when you have found the word and only after checking all the elements in `my_list` evaluate if you have found something, and if not, append the placeholder

```
for x in nm:
    newlist = list()
    for y in x.split():
        for z in mylist:
            if z.lower() == punctuations(y.lower()):
                newlist.append(y)
                break
        else:
            newlist.append('xxx')
    print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're reaching for python's vanilla *string functions* and *regular expressions* when actually your problem is better solved with **formal parsing** using *Parsing Expression Grammar (PEP)*:

For example:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

expr = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("hello") | pp.Word("world") | pp.Word(pp.alphas).setParseAction(pp.replaceWith("XXX")))

expr.parseString("hello foo bar world")
```

Yields:

```py
(['hello', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'world'], {})
```

See module [pyParsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/) and [docs](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Nice, you captured essential behaviour of the OPs code and found an effective library (and concept `PEG`) to solve it elegantly